# how to install TightVnc via remote command prompt‎

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, vnc

How can I install TightVnc via remote command prompt‎? my server: Windows Server 2003 and I don't have any access in my RDP.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have admin access to the server? If you can write to \\servername\c$ you might give the utility [ChrisControl](http://code.google.com/p/chriscontrol/) a shot. Among other things, it can "push" the VNC server to a machine and then start it up for you.